# Подвисает новый компьютер на Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, ос

Купил новый компьютер. Установил windows-10. И начались проблемы. Комп покупал из расчёта просматривать документы и фильмы. Но с этой задачей он справляется совсем не на 100%. Лагает, тупит. Что делать с этим не знаю.

Характеристики ПК:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кажется, что только при запущенных 10 вкладках хрома, не должно быть тормозов у компа в виде подвисающих окон, тупящей мыши и т.п. Я же не грузу процессор вычислениями. При этом, процессор грузится не более чем на 50%. Более не замечал. В чём может быть проблема?

Очень странно, что диспетчер задач пишет, мол отожралось 89% оперативы. Хотя, очевидно, что край, сколько отжирается -- это 2 гига из 4х. Да и то, это я взял с запасом.

Подскажите, в чём может быть беда? Это связано с системой? Или же это, действительно, подозрительное поведение. Опыта общения с виндой у меня мало, поэтому возникают такие вопросы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте Xubuntu - Самая быстрая и удобная ОС на мой взгляд.

Comment: Ваш компьютер поражен Хромом в этом проблема. Каждая его вкладка это отдельный процесс (что и видно на скриншоте. Обратите внимание сколько на каждую вкладку `отъедается` памяти ). Не открывайте много вкладок. На мой взляд мозиловский `Firefox` работает гуманнее )

Comment: А если в Диспетчере задач открыть вкладку Производительность и раздел CPU. Внизу под графиком будет частота процессора (по-английски Speed, по-русски будут "скорость" или "частота"). Понаблюдайте за ней во время загрузки процессора: она поднимается до максимальной? Или не превышает некоего предела? | Есть у меня подозрение, что некоторые апдейты Винды троттлят процессор...

Comment: 4 Gb для Windows 10 это жесть конечно. Тут правильно написал в первом пункте @iluxa1810, вам банально памяти не хватает. И да, Chrome очень сильно память есть. Если память наращивать не собираетесь, уходите на Windows 7 или любой Linux, иначе это ещё цветочки.

Comment: Комп? Не ноутбук?

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf я спрашиваю именно про винду. Не советуйте мне её переустановить и т.п.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Почему же на убунте тогда с хромом не нет проблем? От отжирает память но не 4 гига. В сумме, вместе с ос, это не более 2 гб.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я написал, что загрузка более чем на 50% не просходит.

Comment: @L.F.C. в смысле памяти не хватает? Её в пике не отжирается более 2 Гб. Вы хотите сказать, что в сумме все мелкие процессы по 1-2 мб отжирают 2 гб? Ну, полно.

Comment: @donRumata Ноут

Comment: Если даже под нагрузкой (видео-конвертация, тяжелая игра и т. п.) _частота_ процессора остается на номинальной, то, с большой долей вероятности, это троттлинг по вине Винды. См. [это](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/8d1456d4-e825-4a11-9aac-8cbe117f4137/10571090108810721085108510861077). Принудительно обновитесь до самого свежего апдейта.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопросы связанные с администрацией и железом допустимы если они связаны проф. деятельностью. В данном случае:  "Комп покупал из расчёта просматривать документы и фильмы".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо установить все обновления. Необходимо также учесть специфику ОС работы с часто используемыми файлами. Мой совет - не выключать его и через пару дней ощутите результат. Подробнее: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefetcher

Answer (score 2):

1. 4 гига оперативки даже для обычных нужд уже мало. ~2 гига сжирает ОС+ у вас на скриншоте хром съел еще ~2 гига => уже задействует файл подкачки, который медленный.
2. Вы грешите на процессор, но процессором далеко не все задачи решаются. Например, вы можете загрузить свой HDD так, что ОС будет медленно откливаться из-за огромных очередей чтения/записи.
3. Еще комп может тупить из-за перегрева
4. Еще в какой-то версии Win 10 был баг, что при сортировке по CPU отображались некорректные данные => убедитесь, что ОС последней версии.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы эта конфигурация более-менее прилично жила нужно добавить оперативной памяти хотя бы до 8 гигабайт, и в идеале заменить HDD диск на SSD

Comment: Кажется немного странная история. 8 ГБ для работы с доками? Хм-м-м. Зачем? Это особенность винды?

Comment: Это особенность современных браузеров, например эта страничка у меня занимает 350 Мегабайт памяти, т.е. если открыть с десяток таких вкладок то памяти уже не хватит.

Comment: Это очень странно. Видимо, у Вас мак или винда. На ubuntu новая вкладка и новое окно занимает 120 mb.

Comment: Размер зависит не от ОС, а от браузерного движка и самой странички, хоть под DOS 3.11 открой, но на одном и том-же браузерном движке, одна и та-же страничка будет весить +/- одинакого